# Using new on a function that returns some value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was experimenting with inheritance and creating objects and somehow this confused me.

```
a = function (){console.log("test"); return "hello"};
b = new a();
//console output
 test VM719:2
 a {}
```

What does this mean ? Does it mean b contains a ? if so then if I do this

```
console.log(b.a);
//console output 
 undefined
 undefined
```

Why this is so ?
Secondly if I do this

```
b.__proto__
//console output 
 Object {}
a.prototype.test ="hello";
b.__proto__
//console output 
 Object {test: "hello"}
```

This is fine as new causes b s prototype to point to a.

```
console.log(b);
//console output
 a {test: "hello"}
```

What does this output mean ? When i log b.test it gives "hello" but when i log b.a it gives "undefined" .So what is the significance of a in the output console ?

Comment: it is mean that b is type of a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a constructor function returns nothing, null, or any atomic / non-object value then said value is ignored and the newly created object reference is given back to the caller. So u see the constructor of your object in console...

Comment: +1 for actually explaining what happens with the return value.

Answer (score 3):

`a {}` means is an object instance of `a`, because you used `new` you create an instance. The properties of that object are those of the `prototype` that are shared with all other instances, in your case `test`. **Instance** properties must be created in the constructor, like so:

```
function A() {
  this.prop = 'hello';
}

A.prototype.test = function(){}; // shared with other instances

var b = new A();
b.prop; //=> 'hello' // unique to this instance
```